# How do I check for duplicate IDs from one list in another list?

Tags: sql, xml, vb.net

I will modify the question because it seems I am not supposed to ask a relevant new question.

I would like to use values in list one and check if those values are duplicated in list 2. That is a value in list one can only appear once in list two. If it appears more than once, then it is a duplicate. 
The variable name for the values I am looking for in both lists is **strCaseEventInternalID**

List one **strCaseEventInternalIDList** have 3 values 1810458047, 1810458073 and 1810458074.

List two have 3 values 1810458073, 1810458074 and 1810458074
List two is in this object

```
objXmlResponseDoc2 = Msc.yp.ny.Library.v4.ppp.QueryDB(strSql, "Test", False, True)
```

There is a duplicate (1810458074) in list two which is what I want to find.
How do I do that?

**My vb code**

```
For Each strCaseEventInternalID In strCaseEventInternalIDList
If (strCaseEventInternalIDList.Count() > 1) Then
'Do something
End If
```

Next

Comment: Whats wrong with the answer on your previous question?

Comment: ...and how is this *not* a duplicate of that previous Q?

Comment: In the past I have been asked to instead of modifying a question, if I have more details after getting an answer, it is better to ask a new question. I also did not include the vb code that I have included in this question.

Comment: I need help modify the for each statement.

Comment: Try https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Maybe my question is not clear? List 1 has 3 items and list 2 has 3 items but 2 of the three are duplicates from list one. i.e. 1810458074 from list one appears twice in list two. How do I use a For each and If statements to get that value?